# Substitute a bash script variable twice

Tags: bash, scripting

I would like to know if I can substitute a variable twice.

For example:

```
#global variable 
TEST_SERV_EXT=""

#variables become from myconf.sh
TEST_SERV_EXT_FO='foo01'
TEST_SERV_EXT_BR='bar01'
```

I want dynamically construct those last two and assign them in TEST_SERV_EXT.

I tried something like this ${$TEST_SERV_COMP} but I'm getting "bad substitution" message.

I need something like php's feature "$$" or tcl's subst command.

Regards,
thandem

Comment: What do you mean by: I want dynamically construct those last two and assign them in TEST_SERV_EXT. Do you want to concatenate them?

Comment: Yup, I want to concatenate TEST_SERV_EXT(_FO or _BR) and then get their values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
TEST_SERV_COMP=TEST_SERV_EXT_FO
TEST_SERV_EXT=${!TEST_SERV_COMP}
```

Look for `indirect expansion` in the bash manual.